# Facebook recommend button.. if recommended?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to place a Facebook recommend button on my website. If the user recommends my site, I'd like to show a div with a thank you message. How can I tell if they have clicked the recommend button and that they have actually recommended it on their Facebook wall?

Is there any similar example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the FB.Event.subscribe event to do this. This event is only called if the recommend action was successful.

```
<body> 
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script> 

   FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
        //replace the next line with calling your div
        alert('edge.create fired!');
   });
 </script>
 <fb:like href="" send="false" width="450" show_faces="true" action="recommend" font=""></fb:like>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a Facebook recommend Button:

```
    <div class="fb-like" 
    data-href="http://www.dealdimer.com/" 
    data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-font="verdana" 
    data-colorscheme="dark" data-action="recommend"></div>
```

Change "http://www.dealdimer.com" to your Link.